# How to use ITransform2D on dimension features (arcobjects)

Tags: arcobjects, vba

I am trying to move a dimension feature inside a personal geodatabase using ArcObjects VBA. I was able to move other types of features using similar code as shown below. However it is not working for dimension features. Can someone help me on this?

```
Sub AdjustDimensionFeature()
Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument

Dim pmap As IMap
Set pmap = pMxDoc.FocusMap

Dim pFtrLyr As IFeatureLayer
Set pFtrLyr = pmap.Layer(0)

Dim pFC As IFeatureClass
Set pFC = pFtrLyr.FeatureClass

Dim pFtr As IFeature
Set pFtr = pFC.GetFeature(8362)

Dim pTransform2D As ITransform2D
Dim pPolygon As IPolygon
Set pPolygon = pFtr.ShapeCopy

Set pTransform2D = pPolygon

pTransform2D.Move 20, 20

Set pFtr.Shape = pPolygon

pFtr.Store

End Sub
```

Comment: found the answer myself..

Comment: found the answer myself.. used the dimensionshape property of idimensionfeature..transform BeginDimensionPoint,EndDimensionPoint and DimensionLinePoint..really finding hard to post the code as comment due to formatting :-(

Comment: Post your solution as an answer. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution which i found out..

```
Dim pDimFtr as IDimensionFeature
set pDimFtr = pFtr
Dim pDimShp As IDimensionShape
Set pDimShp = pDimFtr.DimensionShape

Dim pPtsColl As IPointCollection
Set pPtsColl = New Multipoint
pPtsColl.AddPoint pDimShp.BeginDimensionPoint
pPtsColl.AddPoint pDimShp.DimensionLinePoint
pPtsColl.AddPoint pDimShp.EndDimensionPoint
'pPtsColl.AddPoint pDimShp.TextPoint




Dim pTransform2D As ITransform2D
Dim pPolygon As IPolygon
Set pPolygon = pFtr.ShapeCopy

Set pTransform2D = pPtsColl

pTransform2D.Move 20, 20

Set pDimShp.BeginDimensionPoint = pPtsColl.Point(0)
Set pDimShp.DimensionLinePoint = pPtsColl.Point(1)
Set pDimShp.EndDimensionPoint = pPtsColl.Point(2)
'Set pDimShp.TextPoint = pPtsColl.Point(3)


pDimFtr.DimensionShape = pDimShp

pFtr.Store
```

Comment: 3 years down, I face the same issue and woah!!